# how set TimerTask for PrintWriter?

Tags: java, timertask

I am using `TimerTask` to send *messages* every 3 seconds, but its sending only one time.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            soc = new Socket("localhost", 12345);
            out = new PrintWriter(soc.getOutputStream(), true);
            send();
        }
        private static void send() {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    out.println("fetewtewwefwfewf egreg \n");
                    out.flush();
                    InputStream is;
                    try {
                        is = soc.getInputStream();
                        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
                        while (!soc.isClosed()) {
                            long value = dis.readLong();
                            System.out.println(value);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)` which schedules the task only for one execution. For repeated executions use `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`, that is change you code as

```
 timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
     ....
 }, 0, 3000);
```

Comment: is there any difference b/w `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)` and `timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`

Comment: yes, timer.schedule() is fixed-delay. Next task execution is scheduled with a specified delay after the previous task finished. Eg if period = 3 sec and  the task execution takes 1 sec then it will be executed every 4 secs.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at  [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29)

You are using `timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)` which is getting scheduled once.
For repeated scheduling you should use `timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`

But as answered by [Evgeniy Dorofeev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15518708/725306)

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){}, 0, 3000);
```

it does not have an overhead of execution time of your task. And will be executed next time at specific `period`.
While `timer.schedule(TimerTask t, long d, long period)` will include the time of execution of your task, and will be executed next time at the `period` after completion of your previous task.